# Java 1.8 recursive lambdas

Tags: java, recursion, lambda

I do understand the forward reference error, but why do I have to go through the following to
define n!  ?
I have commented out the errors and added the compiler errors I see.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

class Recursion {
    Function<Integer, Integer> factorial_lambda = null;  

    int factorial_imp(int i) {
        if (i == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return i * factorial_imp(i - 1);
    }

    /*
    Function<Integer, Integer>  factorial_lambda = (i) -> {
        if (i == 1)        
            return 1;
        else     
            return i * (factorial_lambda.apply(i - 1));
            // error: self-reference in initializer  
    };
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {  new Recursion(); }

    public Recursion() {
        /*
        Function<Integer, Integer> factorial_lambda = (i) -> { return 1; };
        // variable used in lambda expression should be final 
        // or effectively final;

        // Function factorial_lambda = (i) -> { ...
        //error: imcomparable types: Object and int if (i == 1)
        //error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'  apply(i - 1)
        */
        factorial_lambda = (i) -> {
            if (i == 1)
                return 1;
            else
                return i * (factorial_lambda.apply(i - 1));
        };

        System.out.println(factorial_imp(5));
        System.out.println(factorial_lambda.apply(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles and works properly for me. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that. The question is why does the various commented code fragments not work. For example, I cannot define the lambda factorial_lambda locally in recursion().

Answer (score 1):

1. The first error: "self-reference in initializer". The error message is pretty clear here. It is not allowed to reference a variable in its initializer.
2. This line is not a reason for an error at all. It is absolutely valid and it actually compiles successfully. The reason of this error is that your reassign `factorial_lambda` variable (in the not commented out piece of code) so it stops being effectively final. And it is used inside the lambda expression body. But only final or effectively final local variables are allowed inside a lambda expression body.
3. You use a raw type here. That's why the deduced type of `i` is an `Object`, not an `Integer`. Comparing it with `1` using `==` operator is obviously a compilation error. So is subtracting `1` from it. I would recommend avoiding raw types whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful. The only problem I still have is with 3.  When Iput                                                                    Function <Integer,Integer>factorial_lambda2=(i)->{
                        if (i==1)
                return 1;
            else
                return i*(factorial_lambda2.apply(i-1));
        };                                                         In the body of recursion, I get error: variable factorial_lambda2 might not have been initialized.

Comment: I am not sure if the full response is there. If it is not, when I put        Function <Integer,Integer>factorial_lambda2=(i)->{
                        if (i==1)
                return 1;
            else
                return i*(factorial_lambda2.apply(i-1));
        };                                                        In the body of recursion I get error: variable factorial_lambda2 might not have been initialized.

Comment: @Jerrolds Again, you use a reference to a variable inside its initializer.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a better understanding.